# How to merge multiple text files and save them as csv or txt without sorting error?

Tags: bash, text, preprocessor

I am trying to get all text files in a directory and merge them in line form along with corresponding contents of the file. Data output of the program is

Sample output

```
Filename Contents
001.txt abadsadsad
002.txt abadsadsad
003.txt abadsadsad
```

Desired Output

```
001 abadsadsad       
002 abadsadsad
003 abadsadsad
```

Code:

```
target= echo "Enter target directory: "
read target

mkdir .dump
mv $target/o1.txt $target/.dump/o1-old.txt 
mv $target/o2.txt $target/.dump/o2-old.txt
mv $target/file-content-list.txt $target/.dump/output-old.txt || true #Ensure no o1,o2 and file-content-list.txt file is in target

for f in "$target"/*;
do
    echo -e $(basename "$f" '\t') >>o1.txt && echo $(cat "$f") >>o2.txt
done 
#| awk 'END { printf("File count: %d", NR); } NF=NF' ## Use this one with "done" (previous line) to get file count if needed

paste -d' ' $target/o1.txt $target/o2.txt | column -s $'\t' -t >> file-content-list.txt #Output file is printed. Remove it and from the target if you plan on reusing there.
rm $target/o1.txt 
rm $target/o2.txt
```

How do I optimize this code. Also is there a bash command that can be used to remove the .txt from first column? like a delimiter of sorts? There is also a sorting issue. e.g. if file names are 1,2,3 and so on it sorts them like

```
1
10
2
20
3
```

I always have to endup naming them as 0001 0002 and so on.

How do we fix this?

Comment: Check your script with shellcheck. I do not understand your code - why do you pass `'\t'` to basename?

Comment: Need a tab space in between the contents of file 1 and file 2

Comment: I suggest `awk` for this job.

Comment: How does awk acheive this?

Comment: `Need a tab space in between the contents of file 1 and file 2` How is this related to basename argument? `column` outputs columns delimited by spaces, not by tab. If you want tab, do not use `column`.

Comment: Please add sample input (an extract for example from three files with correct field separtors) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: what happens if an input file has more than one line of content ... append all data into a single line? preface each line of input with the file name (sans '.txt')? something else? please update the question to show a sample file with 2-3 lines of input and the corresponding expected output

Comment: To start I recommend: `grep . "$target"/*`

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
# For each txt file
for f in "$target"/*.txt; do
   # outupt the filename name without .txt extension
   basname "$f" .txt
   # Output the file contents with newlines replaced by a space.
   tr '\n' ' ' <"$f"
done |
# Join two lines of output by a tabulation. The delimiter is arbitrary and is beeing read by column.
paste -d $'\t' - - |
# Columnate the output.
column -s $'\t' -t
```

Answer (score 0):

With [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk)

```bash
gawk '
    BEGINFILE {filename = FILENAME; sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", filename)}
    {print filename, $0}
' *.txt | sort -k1,1n
```

Comment: what does sort k1,1n do?

Comment: Sorts numerically starting from column 1 ending at column 1. I specify the "key" range so that if there are ties, the original order is not changed -- in other words, if the files contain multiple lines, the order is the same as what's in the file.